# NPM - error missing script: dev, but file package.json had "dev"

Tags: vue.js, npm, nuxt.js

I ran `npm run dev` but I do have the following error

> missing script: dev

My `package.json`'s scripts section do have a `"dev": "nuxt"`

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you show me the project structure and make sure that you open the correct folder from your `cmd`

Comment: Are you sure, you are in the same directory in CLI and in the editor? `mxh-frontend` vs `project_mxh-frontend`

Answer (score 1):

delete your `package-lock.json` and do a `npm install`. try again after

Answer (score 1):

You can delete your **node_module** and run this command again **npm install**
If this didn't work you can delete **node_module** and use **yarn install**

Note: you have to have yarn installed on your pc or laptop

then try **npm run dev** again